# How to install Binwalk on Debian without installing the graphs libraries?

Tags: linux, debian, software-installation, python

What is the proper way to install the [Binwalk](http://binwalk.org/installation/) tool on Debian 7.0 without the added graphing capabilities (and it dependencies)? I've read that I can skip the `make deps` command, but this [deps.sh](https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk/blob/master/deps.sh) script installs the required tools, which also includes the Python graphical libraries that I don't want.

EDIT: I uncommented in [deps.sh](http://pastebin.com/RfVc3QiK) code, that installs python graphing libraries.
Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: Looking at most of those dependencies indicates a heavy need for python, as most of them are the python bindings.  Are you sure you want to strip Python of power?

Comment: Binwalk itself is Python script, I just don't need binwalk’s **graphing** capabilities, therefore don't need pyqtgraph and its required dependencies (libqt4-opengl, python-opengl, python-qt4, python-qt4-gl, python-numpy, python-scipy).

Comment: If the developer doesn't provide a non-graphing option, you may need to contact them.  Try forking his repository if you like, and manually remove them.

Comment: Its possible to use binwalk without graphing capabilities, I need more specific how to install it without that libraries.

Comment: You can't do this unless you modify his python script and remove references to PyQt4, as there is no configure option to disable PyQt4.

Comment: From [installation manual](http://binwalk.org/installation/) I read its possible.

Comment: See my Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Per the instruction manual, you linked above, you want to skip the optional dependencies, so we skip:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-opengl python-opengl python-qt4 python-qt4-gl python-numpy python-scipy
wget -O - http://www.pyqtgraph.org/downloads/pyqtgraph-0.9.8.tar.gz | tar -zxv && cd pyqtgraph-0.9.8 && sudo pyth
```

and then during the build/compile phase we skip `make deps`.  In the binwalk source directory, run these commands in this order:

1. `sudo apt-get install build-essential libtool autoconf`
2. `./configure`
3. `make`
4. `sudo make install`

**Update**

To install the Firmware Mod Kit:

1. `sudo mkdir /opt/firmware-mod-kit/.git`
2. `cd /opt/firmware-mod-kit/.git`
3. `git clone http://code.google.com/p/firmware-mod-kit`
4. `cd /opt/firmware-mod-kit/src`
5. `./configure && sudo make`

Comment: And I still need to use [deps.sh](http://pastebin.com/RfVc3QiK) script I modded (lines 71-74 and 82-85) for installing other stuff?

Comment: No you don't need the deps script... the deps script runs when you use `make deps` but since I advised you to skip it, it's never used.

Comment: But I need firmware-mod-kit and it pre-requisites and extraction tools: should I install it separately?

Comment: Yes as the instruction I gave you removed the dependencies

Comment: Can I do the same using modified deps.sh in `make deps` step?

Comment: Why would you want to when `deps.sh` is used for the graphing you want to get rid of?  `make deps` invokes `deps.sh`

Comment: Deps.sh installs all other dependencies, firmware-mod-kit and extraction utilities, not not only graphing libs. I uncommented graphing libs.

Comment: See update in answer

Comment: The one step remains to install extraction uttilities (mtd-utils unrar zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev xz-devel compress gzip bzip2 tar arj lha p7zip p7zip-full openjdk-6-jdk)

Comment: Pick your distro and either copy and run lines 70-71 or 81