# Can not run configure command: "No such file or directory"

Tags: compiling, configure, autotools

I'm trying to install a Debian package from source (via git). I downloaded the
package, changed to the package’s directory and ran `./configure` command but
it returned `bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`. What can be the
problem? A `configure.ac` file is located in the program folder.

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: What Package are you trying to install??

Comment: @eyoung100 binwalk

Comment: See [Install Binwalk Without Graphing](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157248/how-to-install-binwalk-on-debian-without-installing-the-graphs-libraries/157309#157309).  Of course if you need the graphing dont skip `make deps`.  If it helps, just upvote me, and I'll know it was you :)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**If the file is called configure.ac,**

*do* `$> autoconf`

Depends:
M4, Automake

**If you're not sure what to do,**

*try* `$> cat readme`

They must mean that you use "autoconf" to generate an executable "configure" file.

So the order is:

```
$> autoconf
$> ./configure
$> make
$> make install
```

Comment: You mean use `autoconf` before `./configure`?

Comment: You use autoconf instead of make when you have a .ac file. It replaces ./configure.

Comment: so, `./configure` and `make` commands both skipped, only **autoconf**, then **make install**?

Comment: It's autoconf, then ./configure, then make, then make install. Doesn't your package have a READ-ME? It's $> autoconf $> ./configure $> automake... I think that's how it goes. It's been a while since I've installed an autoconf package.

Comment: Interesting. Manual says installation "follows the typical configure/make process" I've specified above. Autoconf is not not mentioned.

Comment: Send me a link to the package, so I can try to build it, triwo.

Answer (score 24):

The failsafe for generating a configure script is `autoreconf -i`, which not only takes care of calling `autoconf` itself, but also a host of other tools that may be needed.

Comment: autoreconf: `configure.ac' or `configure.in' is required.

Comment: @Mr.Hyde Well, obviously it only works for projects that *use* autoconf.

Comment: @user3338098 If you've installed your distro's "all important build tools" package (Debian/Ubuntu `apt-get install build-essential`), it should include that already I think?

Comment: I, for one, can attest that `autoreconf -i` is the correct solution.

Comment: Worked just great for me.